# Home screen is not clickable in ionic cordova iOS build

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an ionic cordova app which is working fine on Android device, but during iOS build there are some issues

1. Not able to click on any button, any text field on the screen.

[image]

2. Image above the text fields is overriding the text area. Also half of the image is not shown up on the screen.

Comment: What is the IOS version you use?

Comment: 10.12.5, and I am using ios imulator iphone 7 to view the app

Comment: Once i had the same issue. Check this link. Once I updated cordova-ios plugin, it worked for me, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10530?focusedCommentId=15149506&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15149506

Comment: Thank you, I will try this, but is there any option we can handle this using custom scripts ?

Comment: I don't know if there is. The only thing helped to solve our issue is that one

Comment: but there is no cordova plugin-ios my project is using. however I am using cordova platform ios@3.4.4

Comment: think https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1094 is your issue..try reverting app scripts version if it is 2.0

Comment: @sparrowTrajon im sorry, i meant update cordova platform ios

Comment: Okay, No problem thank you

Comment: Did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Everything in the home screen is stuck in IOS, while android works without any issue. Check [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10530?focusedCommentId=15149506&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15149506) discussion. Once I updated cordova-ios platform as suggested here, it worked for me

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but its not working in my case.

Not able to click anywhere on the screen even after updating the ios platform to latest